# Ubuntu Server 20.04 showing wrong storage size

Tags: storage

When I am using `df -h --total`, it shows 131 GB as total even though the hard drive is 256 GB big. Did I make a mistake while setting up the server and can I increase this size?

`lsblk` output:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop1                       7:1    0  70.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21029
loop2                       7:2    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
loop3                       7:3    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13170
loop4                       7:4    0  61.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1081
loop5                       7:5    0  67.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21545
sda                         8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   237G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 118.5G  0 lvm  /
```

`df -h --total` output:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              783M  1.4M  781M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  117G  6.5G  104G   6% /
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop1                          71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
/dev/sda2                          976M  107M  802M  12% /boot
/dev/loop2                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
/dev/sda1                          511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop3                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/13170
/dev/loop4                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1081
/dev/loop5                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21545
tmpfs                              783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/1000
total                              131G  7.0G  118G   6% -
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add `lsblk` output together with `df -h` output.

Comment: I am completely new to Linux what is lsblk? And now that I do see the storage how can I assign (partition?) it to ubuntu so it is usable?

Comment: You should `lvextend` your "root" logical volume. See for example this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209796/make-lvm-volume-take-up-entire-disk

Comment: I have also noticed, that the installer of Ubuntu Live Server grabs half of the available drive space. It leaves drive space if you want to use [snapshots](https://tutonics.com/2012/12/lvm-guide-part-2-snapshots.html), but you can easily increase the drive space used for the root file system as described in the comment by @FedonKadifeli.